How can we deploy PY files without converting to Exe file and without Python installed on user system?
While executing the EXE file, we can't able to access the exe file due to environment and network constraint, we need to deploy the process in the user system without converting PY files to exe.
We tried to deploy via batch files, but the tool is not getting executed.

How about providing the user with a portable python distribution to execute the tool with. This could work from a shared network drive but is quite slow...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
